# Excel VBA excluir item de ListBox

Tags: microsoft-excel, listbox, excel-vba

Estou com dificuldade em excluir um item de um `listbox`.
O código funciona assim: vai ter o `listbox` com a lista, e quando o usuário quiser excluir algum item, ele clica em um botão que abre um outro `userform`, nesse `userform` o usuário insere o numero do item a ser excluído no `listbox`, junto com um `msgbox` para pedir a confirmação da exclusão.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim curso

    resposta = MsgBox("Deseja excluir o curso?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Excluir?")
    If resposta = vbYes Then
        curso = TextBox1.Text
        UserForm2.ListBox1.RemoveItem (curso)
    End If
End Sub
```

Por questões de funcionalidade, preferiria que o código funcionasse assim, com duas confirmações diferentes (informar explicitamente o número do item a ser excluído e a `msgbox`).

Estou aberto a opiniões.

Comment: qual o erro que acontece?

Comment: Aparece como "Erro não especificado" e trava na linha do `ListBox.RemoveItem`.
Procurando na net, achava muitos exemplos de códigos que excluíam quando o item estava selecionado. Mas como disse, não é a forma que eu quero fazer. Acabei achando umas 3 formas diferentes de usar o `.RemoveItem` e excluir um item do `ListBox` e tentei adaptar todos no meu código mas nenhum funcionou.
Imagino que esteja errando na sintaxe dele!

Answer (score 1):

### Para selecionar um item de cada vez

#### Este código remove o item selecionado

```
'''
'Remover item
'''  
'Remove item selecionado da lista 1

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)
    End If
Next i
```

#### Limpar ListBox

`Me.ListBox1.Clear`

#### Confirmação antes de excluir o item

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '''
    'Remover item
    '''
    Dim counter As Integer
    'Remove item selecionado da lista 1
    With Me
        For i = 0 To .ListBox1.ListCount - 1
            If .ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
                resposta = MsgBox("Deseja excluir o item: " & .ListBox1.List(i) & "?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Excluir?")
                If vbYes Then .ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)
            End If
        Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

### Multiseleção

Há três opções de `Multiselect`:

- `ListBox.MultiSelect = 0`: Selecionar somente um elemento. (Métodos de remoção de itens explicado anteriormente)
- `ListBox.MultiSelect = 1`: Clicar no item ou pressionar a barra de espaço para selecionar múltiplos itens
- `ListBox.MultiSelect = 2`: Pressione Shift e Ctrl para selecionar múltiplos itens

Código:

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Me.ListBox1.MultiSelect = Número_Multiselect
    End Sub
```

#### Remover/Excluir Múltiplos itens com confirmação individual

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '''
    'Remover item
    '''
    'Remove item selecionado da lista 1
    With Me
        For i = .ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
                resposta = MsgBox("Deseja excluir o item: " & .ListBox1.List(i) & "?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Excluir?")
                If vbYes Then .ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

#### Remover/Excluir Múltiplos itens com confirmação múltipla

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '''
    'Remover item
    '''
    'Remove item selecionado da lista 1
    Dim i As Long, contador As Long
    Dim vetor() As Variant
    With Me
        For i = .ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
                ReDim Preserve vetor(contador)
                msg = msg & vbCrLf & .ListBox1.List(i)
                vetor(contador) = i
                contador = contador + 1
            End If
        Next i
        resposta = MsgBox("Deseja excluir os itens a seguir? " & msg, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Excluir?")
        If vbYes Then
            For i = LBound(vetor) To UBound(vetor)
                .ListBox1.RemoveItem (vetor(i))
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

## Pelo Número do item:

No caso de querer remover pelo número do item, fique ciente que a lista se inicia em zero.

Para um exemplo em que a ListBox está no Userform1 e a entrada do número do item está no Userform2, com um botão de comando e uma caixa de texto:

#### Userform1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

#### Userform2

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '''
    'Remover item
    '''
    'Remove item selecionado da lista 1
    With UserForm1
         i = Me.TextBox1
        resposta = MsgBox("Deseja excluir o item: " & .ListBox1.List(i) & "?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Excluir?")
        If vbYes Then .ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)
    End With

    Me.Hide
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

#### Lista iniciando em 1

Caso deseje que a lista inicie em 1, o código do Userform2 fica da seguinte maneira:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With UserForm1
         i = Me.TextBox1
        resposta = MsgBox("Deseja excluir o item: " & .ListBox1.List(i - 1) & "?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Excluir?")
        If vbYes Then .ListBox1.RemoveItem (i - 1)
    End With

    Me.Hide
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Bacana a resposta, mas para que ela atenda ao que foi pedido na pergunta teria que ter também a forma de excluir um item da lista sem que ele esteja selecionado, pelo número do item!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ListBox1.AddItem "teste"

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim curso

    resposta = MsgBox("Deseja excluir o curso?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Excluir?")
    If resposta = vbYes Then
        curso = TextBox1.Text
        UserForm1.ListBox1.RemoveItem (curso)
    End If

End Sub
```

Testei com esse código aqui e funcionou. A única diferença é que a caixa de texto que informa a posição do item a ser excluído está no mesmo UserForm.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não funcionou!
Aparece "Erro de compilação - Argumento nomeado não localizado"

Se não me engano, tinha tentado assim já!

Algum detalhe do .`.RemoveItem` que estou deixando passar!

Comment: Tenta tirar esse "UserForm2." deixa só o ListBox.RemoveItem